# Android GEO Location Tutorial

Tags: android, geo

Does anyone know a good GEO Location tutorial for Android. I don’t want to have to get a Google maps API key I just want an Activity that gets the location of a phone and sticks it in a variable that I can then decide what to do with it later.

Cheers,

Mike.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Only for location then Just go through [Using GPS to get current location – Android tutorial](http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/04/29/android-development-using-gps-to-get-current-location-2/)

[Find Current Location in Android - GPS Sample](http://about-android.blogspot.com/2010/04/find-current-location-in-android-gps.html)

[Android Location Based Services Application – GPS location](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/09/android-location-based-services.html)

[Obtaining User Location](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html)

[Location Manager Examples](http://vinnysoft.blogspot.com/2009/10/location-manager-examples.html)